# Prolog no_duplicate function

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I'm trying to write a simple procedure that checks if a list has any duplicates.  This is what I have tried so far:

```
% returns true if the list has no duplicate items.
no_duplicates([X|XS]) :- member(X,XS) -> false ; no_duplicates(XS).
no_duplicates([]) :- true.
```

If I try `no_duplicates([1,2,3,3])`. It says true. Why is this? I'm probably misunderstanding Prolog here, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: I assume you are using SWI Prolog (since you have the swi-prolog tag in the question). I tested your program with SWI 6.6.6 and it works for the case you mentioned, giving me `false`.

Comment: That's weird.. I'm using 6.6.6 as well, and it gives me true.

Comment: How did you load the code? Did you put it in a file (say, "`dup.prolog`") then loaded it into SWI with `['dup.prolog'].` before asking the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go at the problem more descriptively:

```
no_duplicates( []     ) .  % the empty list is unique
no_duplicates( [X|Xs] ) :- % a list of length 1+ is unique
  \+ member(X,Xs) ,        % - if its head is not found in the tail,
  no_duplicates(Xs)        % - and its tail is itself unique.
  .                        %
```

Thinking on this, since this is a somewhat expensive operation — O(n<sup>2</sup>)? — it might be more efficient to use `sort/2` and take advantage of the fact that it produces an ordered set, removing duplicates. You could say something like

```
no_duplicates( L ) :-
  sort(L,R)   , % sort the source list, removing duplicates
  length(L,N) , % determine the length of the source list
  length(R,N) . % check that against the result list
```

Or you could use `msort/3` (which doesn't remove duplicates), might be a bit faster, too:

```
no_duplicates( L ) :-
  msort(L,R),            % order the list
  \+ append(_,[X,X|_],R) % see if we can find two consecutive identical members
  .
```

Comment: OP's solution is right. And yours gives one alternative, so it isn't false, but there aren't two altering ways of no duplicates in a list. so this isn't a good solution. I'd remove the singelton list case.

Comment: This last version with `msort/2` and syntactic unification exposes even more erratic behavior than your original solution.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your questions: your solution actually fails as expected for `no_duplicates([1,2,3,3])`. So there is no problem.

Now take the queries:

```
?- A = 1, no_duplicates([A, 2]).
A = 1.
?-        no_duplicates([A, 2]), A = 1.
```

They both mean the same, so we should expect that Prolog will produce the same answer. (<sub>To be more precise we expect the same ignoring errors and non-termination</sub>).

However, four proposed solutions differ! And the one that does not, differs for:

```
?- A = 2, no_duplicates([A, 2]).
false.
?-        no_duplicates([A, 2]), A = 2.
```

Note that it is always the second query that makes troubles.  To solve this problem we need a good answer for `no_duplicates([A, 2])`. It cannot be `false`, since there are some values for `A` to make it true. Like `A = 1`. Nor can it be true, since some values do not fit, like `A = 2`.

Another possibility would be to issue an `instantiation_error` in this case. Meaning: I have not enough information so I better stop than mess around with potentially incorrect information.

Ideally, we get one answer that covers all possible solutions. This answer is `dif(A, 2)` which means that all `A` that are different to 2 are solutions.

`dif/2` is one of the oldest built-in predicates, already Prolog 0 did possess it. Unfortunately, later developments discarded it in Prolog I and thus Edinburgh Prolog and thus ISO Prolog.

However, [current systems](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dif) including SICStus, YAP, SWI all offer it. And there is a safe way to [approximate `dif/2` safely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238931/772868) in ISO-Prolog

```
no_duplicates(Xs) :-
   all_different(Xs). % the common name

all_different([]).
all_different([X|Xs]) :-
   maplist(dif(X),Xs).
   all_different(Xs).
```

See: [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)

Answer (score 3):

Here's yet another approach, which works because `sort/2` removes duplicates:

```
no_duplicates(L) :-
    length(L, N),
    sort(L, LS),
    length(LS, N).
```

Answer (score 2):

Duplicates in a list are same elements not at the same place in the list, so no_duplicates can be written :

```
no_duplicates(L) :-
    \+((nth0(Id1, L, V), nth0(Id2, L, V), Id1 \= Id2)).
```

Comment: You can also try `append(_, [E | R], L), member(E, R)`—might be faster, as it avoids explicit comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Jay already noted that your code is working. An alternative, slightly less verbose

```
no_duplicates(L) :- \+ (append(_, [X|XS], L), memberchk(X, XS)).
```