# Numbers in a list smaller than a given number

Tags: list, prolog

```
xMenores(_,[],[]).
xMenores(X,[H|T],[R|Z]) :-
   xMenores(X,T,Z),
   X > H,
   R is H.
```

`xMenores` takes three parameters:

- The first one is a number.
- The second is a list of numbers.
- The third is a list and is the variable that will contain the result.

The objective of the rule `xMenores` is obtain a list with the numbers of the list (Second parameter) that are smaller than the value on the first parameter. For example:

```
?- xMenores(3,[1,2,3],X).
X = [1,2].                        % expected result
```

The problem is that `xMenores` returns `false` when `X > H` is false and my programming skills are almost null at prolog. So:

```
?- xMenores(4,[1,2,3],X).
X = [1,2,3].                      % Perfect.

?- xMenores(2,[1,2,3],X).
false.                            % Wrong! "X = [1]" would be perfect.
```

I consider `X > H, R is H.` because I need that whenever `X` is bigger than `H`, `R` takes the value of `H`. But I don't know a control structure like an if or something in Prolog to handle this.

Please, any solution? Thanks.

Comment: in SWI, try ?- [include](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3)(>(2),[4,1,2,3],L).

Comment: Yes. But the point was to make it myself, with my own code or at least to know who to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Using `( if -> then ; else )`

The control structure you might be looking for is `( if -> then ; else )`.

**Warning**: you should probably swap the order of the first two arguments:

```
lessthan_if([], _, []).
lessthan_if([X|Xs], Y, Zs) :-
    (   X < Y
    ->  Zs = [X|Zs1]
    ;   Zs = Zs1
    ),
    lessthan_if(Xs, Y, Zs1).
```

**However**, if you are writing real code, you should almost certainly go with one of the predicates in [library(apply)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply), for example `include/3`, as [suggested by @CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260202/numbers-of-a-list-smaller-than-some-x-number#comment52400484_32260202):

```
?- include(>(3), [1,2,3], R).
R = [1, 2].

?- include(>(4), [1,2,3], R).
R = [1, 2, 3].

?- include(<(2), [1,2,3], R).
R = [3].
```

See [the implementation of `include/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/apply.pl?show=src#include/3) if you want to know how this kind of problems are solved. You will notice that `lessthan/3` above is nothing but a specialization of the more general `include/3` in library(apply): `include/3` will reorder the arguments and use the `( if -> then ; else )`.

### "Declarative" solution

Alternatively, a less "procedural" and more "declarative" predicate:

```
lessthan_decl([], _, []).
lessthan_decl([X|Xs], Y, [X|Zs]) :- X < Y,
    lessthan_decl(Xs, Y, Zs).
lessthan_decl([X|Xs], Y, Zs) :- X >= Y,
    lessthan_decl(Xs, Y, Zs).
```

(`lessthan_if/3` and `lessthan_decl/3` are nearly identical to the [solutions by Nicholas Carey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32260581/1812457), except for the order of arguments.)

On the downside, `lessthan_decl/3` leaves behind choice points. However, it is a good starting point for a general, readable solution. We need two code transformations:

1. Replace the arithmetic comparisons `<` and `>=` with CLP(FD) constraints: `#<` and `#>=`;
2. Use a DCG rule to get rid of arguments in the definition.

You will arrive at the [solution by lurker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279417/1812457).

### A different approach

The most general comparison predicate in Prolog is [`compare/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=compare/3). A common pattern using it is to explicitly enumerate the three possible values for `Order`:

```
lessthan_compare([], _, []).
lessthan_compare([H|T], X, R) :-
    compare(Order, H, X),
    lessthan_compare_1(Order, H, T, X, R).

lessthan_compare_1(<, H, T, X, [H|R]) :-
    lessthan_compare(T, X, R).
lessthan_compare_1(=, _, T, X, R) :-
    lessthan_compare(T, X, R).
lessthan_compare_1(>, _, T, X, R) :-
    lessthan_compare(T, X, R).
```

(Compared to any of the other solutions, this one would work with any terms, not just integers or arithmetic expressions.)

Replacing `compare/3` with [`zcompare/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=zcompare/3):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

lessthan_clpfd([], _, []).
lessthan_clpfd([H|T], X, R) :-
    zcompare(ZOrder, H, X),
    lessthan_clpfd_1(ZOrder, H, T, X, R).

lessthan_clpfd_1(<, H, T, X, [H|R]) :-
    lessthan_clpfd(T, X, R).
lessthan_clpfd_1(=, _, T, X, R) :-
    lessthan_clpfd(T, X, R).
lessthan_clpfd_1(>, _, T, X, R) :-
    lessthan_clpfd(T, X, R).
```

This is definitely more code than any of the other solutions, but it does not leave behind unnecessary choice points:

```
?- lessthan_clpfd(3, [1,3,2], Xs).
Xs = [1, 2]. % no dangling choice points!
```

In the other cases, it behaves just as the DCG solution by lurker:

```
?- lessthan_clpfd(X, [1,3,2], Xs).
Xs = [1, 3, 2],
X in 4..sup ;
X = 3,
Xs = [1, 2] ;
X = 2,
Xs = [1] ;
X = 1,
Xs = [] .

?- lessthan_clpfd(X, [1,3,2], Xs), X = 3. %
X = 3,
Xs = [1, 2] ; % no error!
false.

?- lessthan_clpfd([1,3,2], X, R), R = [1, 2].
X = 3,
R = [1, 2] ;
false.
```

Unless you need such a general approach, `include(>(X), List, Result)` is good enough.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted this one because it's an improvement to the [solution by Nicholas Carey](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32260581/1812457). Perfect!

Comment: While `include/3` often exposes non-relational behavior, it is this time - with arithmetical expressions perfect to use.

Comment: @repeat It is then difficult to discuss the different approaches. Will edit this answer to be a bit more explicit about the pros and cons of each solution.

Comment: Consider these two queries: `?- lessthan_compare([1,2,3],4,Xs).` and `?- lessthan_compare([1,2,3],X,Xs), X=4.`

Comment: @repeat Yes, obviously, `zcompare/3` will work even if 2nd and 3rd arguments are not instantiated, which is the reason why I used it, right? On the other hand, you give away the ability to compare arbitrary terms.

Comment: @repeat The whole point of writing this answer in this way is that writing code is an iterative process. I am as interested in the end result as in the way to get there: this is how I try to learn.

Comment: The version using `compare/3` may give answers that do not hold for all possible values the variables used can take. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720685/safe-term-order. The variant using `zcompare/3` **is** safe!

Comment: Right now, you are in the lead with your implementation using `zcompare/3`... But I guess the code could shrink 50+% if you used `if_/3` and `(#>)/3` instead. 3 days remaining. tik, tok. I'd say: go for it!

Comment: @repeat "3 days remaining. tik, tok" what is this, a game show? ;) but yeah, I am quite ok with the solution as it stands, I am really not _that_ hot for imaginary internet points.

Comment: Dang! I probably shouldn't have written "you are in the lead" in the first sentence;) Btw. it's never about the points, always about learning.

Comment: @repeat Sure, but every one of us has a limited time on their hands. I would gladly learn from someone else's solution. And I do prefer obvious code over concise code most of the time. Since I am not experienced with using `is_/3` and `(#>)/3`, _in my eyes_ a solution using those stops being obvious. (I feel the same about lambdas in Prolog, but this is another discussion altogether.)

Comment: Okay, I get that! How about this? I'll take some answer using `if_/3` and `(#>)/3` and add some "in-between" code to *bridge the gap* (code that is semantically equivalent, but may still produce unneeded choicepoints).

Comment: @repeat sure, knock yourself out

Comment: @boris. **Alright!** May the "revision log" be my witness;) But seriously, I'm always thankful for comments pointing out issues: Not only errors / inconsistencies, but equally important, if not more so, problems like lack of clarity, "bumpy" presentation style, etc.

Answer (score 11):

This can also be done using a DCG:

```
less_than([], _) --> [].
less_than([H|T], N) --> [H], { H #< N }, less_than(T, N).
less_than(L, N) --> [H], { H #>= N }, less_than(L, N).

| ?- phrase(less_than(R, 4), [1,2,3,4,5,6]).

R = [1,2,3] ? ;
```

You can write your predicate as:

```
xMenores(N, NumberList, Result) :- phrase(less_than(Result, N), NumberList).
```

Comment: In my view, this is by far the best solution posted so far in this thread: It is very readable and also very general. +1! Supposing of course that the problem is posed over integers, which indeed seems to be the case from the examples, and as is also typical.

Comment: s(X). Nice, highly correct, but inefficient. Why not consider an answer using `if_/3` or even `if_//3`? There will be no implementation in the world that is able to make your code as it is now determinate as it should be for given N and list.

Comment: @false yes, I know it's inefficient and non-deterministic.I offered it as a way to "see the problem with DCG glasses", but with now efficiency warranties expressed or implied.Regarding `if_/3` and `if_//3`, I haven't (yet) become accustomed to using them.

Comment: Promise: Will put a bounty for such an implementation ASAP!

Comment: @repeat I made a couple of attempts using those predicates but kept ending up with the choice point. I hadn't gotten back to resolving it.

Comment: @repeat - I updated my answer to use a standard conditional. When using an `if_/3`, there's still a choice point, which I think is due to the fact that `less_than([], N)` can match an empty input list for termination, or a non-empty list in the case the remaining elements of the input are not less than `N`. I shall post this as a separate question, as you suggest, and link back to this one. Hopefully I can get to this tonight when I have a little more time.

Comment: The bounty's still in reach... join the `if_/3` revolution!

Comment: @repeat thanks for the encouragement. I tried an `if_/3` approach and still had a choice point. Haven't had time to work it further.

Comment: Thank you for trying! Will do another bounty... Don't worry: `if_/3` is here to stay—it's monotone:)

Answer (score 5):

You could write it as a one-liner using `findall\3`:

```
filter( N , Xs , Zs ) :- findall( X, ( member(X,Xs), X < N ) , Zs ) .
```

However, I suspect that the point of the exercise is to learn about recursion, so something like this would work:

```
filter( _ , []     , []     ) .
filter( N , [X|Xs] , [X|Zs] ) :- X <  N , filter(N,Xs,Zs) .
filter( N , [X|Xs] , Zs     ) :- X >= N , filter(N,Xs,Zs) .
```

It does, however, unpack the list twice on backtracking. An optimization here would be to combine the 2nd and 3rd clauses by introducing a *soft cut* like so:

```
filter( _ , []     , []     ) .
filter( N , [X|Xs] , [X|Zs] ) :-
  ( X < N -> Zs = [X|Z1] ; Zs = Z1 ) ,
  filter(N,Xs,Zs)
  .
```

Comment: In SWI "soft-cut" refers to `(*->)/2`, not `(->)/2`.

Comment: A perfect answer (+1), but note that the predicates in library(apply) are probably a better one-liner approach than findall+member, and `include/3` is identical to your last solution.

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution Nicholas!

Comment: @repeat: This is not specific to SWI. Soft cut always means `if/3` or `(*->)/2` - see Negation and Control in Prolog by Lee Naish, LNCS 238

Comment: Join the bounty hunt by using `tfilter/3` in a one-liner!

Answer (score 5):

(This is more like a comment than an answer, but too long for a comment.)

Some previous answers and comments have suggested using "if-then-else" `(->)/2` or using `library(apply)` [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `include/3`. Both methods work alright, as long as only plain-old Prolog arithmetics—`is/2`, `(>)/2`, and the like—are used ...

```
?- X = 3, include(>(X),[1,3,2,5,4],Xs).
X = 3, Xs = [1,2].

?-        include(>(X),[1,3,2,5,4],Xs), X = 3.
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
% This is OK. When instantiation is insufficient, an exception is raised.
```

..., but when doing the *seemingly benign switch* from `(>)/2` to `(#>)/2`, we lose soundness!

```
?- X = 3, include(#>(X),[1,3,2,5,4],Xs).
X = 3, Xs = [1,2].

?-        include(#>(X),[1,3,2,5,4],Xs), X = 3.
false.
% This is BAD! Expected success with answer substitutions `X = 3, Xs = [1,2]`.
```

Comment: See the addition to my original answer above. It is unnecessary, I feel, but since you insist :)

Comment: @Boris. Ok. Please explain what you mean with "it is unnecessary".

Comment: Ok, I take "unnecessary" back. Was not certain in what situation such a predicate would be needed.

Answer (score 5):

*No new code* is presented in this answer.

In the following we take a detailed look at different revisions of [this answer by @lurker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279417/4609915).

---

**[Revision #1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32279417/1)**, renamed to `less_than_ver1//2`. By using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) and [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), the code is **both very readable and versatile**:

```
less_than_ver1(_, []) --> [].
less_than_ver1(N, [H|T]) --> [H], { H #< N }, less_than_ver1(N, T).
less_than_ver1(N, L) --> [H], { H #>= N }, less_than_ver1(N, L).
```

Let's query!

```
?-  phrase(less_than_ver1(N,Zs),[1,2,3,4,5]).
  N in 6..sup, Zs = [1,2,3,4,5]
; N  = 5     , Zs = [1,2,3,4]
; N  = 4     , Zs = [1,2,3]
; N  = 3     , Zs = [1,2]
; N  = 2     , Zs = [1]
; N in inf..1, Zs = []
; false.

?- N = 3, phrase(less_than_ver1(N,Zs),[1,2,3,4,5]).
  N = 3, Zs = [1,2]       % succeeds, but leaves useless choicepoint
; false.

?-        phrase(less_than_ver1(N,Zs),[1,2,3,4,5]), N = 3.
  N = 3, Zs = [1,2]
; false.
```

As a *small imperfection*, `less_than_ver1//2` leaves some useless choicepoints.

Let's see how things went with the newer revision...

---

**[Revision #3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32279417/1)**, renamed to `less_than_ver3//2`:

```
less_than_ver3([],_) --> [].
less_than_ver3(L,N) --> [X], { X #< N -> L=[X|T] ; L=T }, less_than_ver3(L,N).
```

This code uses the if-then-else (`(->)/2` + `(;)/2`) in order to improve determinism.

Let's simply re-run the above queries!

```
?- phrase(less_than_ver3(Zs,N),[1,2,3,4,5]).
  N in 6..sup, Zs = [1,2,3,4,5]
; false.                              % all other solutions are missing!

?- N = 3, phrase(less_than_ver3(Zs,N),[1,2,3,4,5]).
  N = 3, Zs = [1,2]                   % works as before, but no better.
; false.                              % we still got the useless choicepoint

?-        phrase(less_than_ver3(Zs,N),[1,2,3,4,5]), N = 3.
false.                                % no solution! 
                                      % we got one with revision #1!
```

Surprise! Two cases that worked before are now (somewhat) broken, and the determinism in the ground case is no better... *Why?*

1. The vanilla if-then-else often cuts too much too soon, which is particularly problematic with code which uses coroutining and/or constraints.

   Note that `(*->)/2` (a.k.a. "soft-cut" or `if/3`), fares only a bit better, not a lot!
2. As `if_/3` never ever cuts more (often than) the vanilla if-then-else `(->)/2`, it cannot be used in above code to improve determinism.
3. If you want to use `if_/3` in combination with constraints, take a step back and write code that is non-[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) as the first shot.
4. If you're lazy like me, consider using a [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) like `tfilter/3` and `(#>)/3`.

Comment: Yeah sorry I need another cup of coffee... Still, you're post is very helpful in its analysis (+1).

Comment: Ok, no harm done. Don't hesitate to post independent (additional) new answers. When shifting the focus on determinism, it's easier to first consider the non-dcg case.

Answer (score 4):

[This answer by @Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32266555/4609915) presented a logically pure solution which utilizes [`clpfd:zcompare/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) to help improve determinism in certain (ground) cases.

In this answer we will explore different ways of coding logically pure Prolog while trying to avoid the creation of useless choicepoints.

---

Let's get started with `zcompare/3` and `(#<)/3`!

- `zcompare/3` implements [three-way comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison) of finite domain variables and reifies the trichotomy into one of `<`, `=`, or `>`.
- As the inclusion criterion used by the OP was a arithmetic less-than test, we propose using 
  [`(#<)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059035/4609915) for reifying the dichotomy into one of `true` or `false`.

Consider the answers of the following queries:

```
?- zcompare(Ord,1,5), #<(1,5,B).
Ord = (<), B = true.    

?- zcompare(Ord,5,5), #<(5,5,B).
Ord = (=), B = false.   

?- zcompare(Ord,9,5), #<(9,5,B).
Ord = (>), B = false.
```

Note that for all items to be selected both `Ord = (<)` *and* `B = true` holds.

---

Here's a side-by-side comparison of three non-[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) solutions based on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

- The left one uses `zcompare/3` and first-argument indexing on the three cases `<`, `=`, and `>`.
- The middle one uses `(#<)/3` and first-argument indexing on the two cases `true` and `false`.
- The right one uses `(#<)/3` in combination with [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915).

Note that we do not need to define auxiliary predicates in the right column!

```
less_than([],[],_).       % less_than([],[],_).          % less_than([],[],_).
less_than([Z|Zs],Ls,X) :- % less_than([Z|Zs],Ls,X) :-    % less_than([Z|Zs],Ls,X) :-
   zcompare(Ord,Z,X),     %    #<(Z,X,B),                %    if_(Z #< X,
   ord_lt_(Ord,Z,Ls,Rs),  %    incl_lt_(B,Z,Ls,Rs),      %        Ls = [Z|Rs],
   less_than(Zs,Rs,X).    %    less_than(Zs,Rs,X).       %        Ls = Rs),
                          %                              %    less_than(Zs,Rs,X).   
ord_lt_(<,Z,[Z|Ls],Ls).   % incl_lt_(true ,Z,[Z|Ls],Ls). %
ord_lt_(=,_,   Ls ,Ls).   % incl_lt_(false,_,   Ls ,Ls). %    
ord_lt_(>,_,   Ls ,Ls).   %                              %
```

---

Next, let's use [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)!

- In the right column we use [`if_//3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367581/4609915) instead of [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915).
- Note the different argument orders of [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) and non-[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) solutions: `less_than([1,2,3],Zs,3)` vs `phrase(less_than([1,2,3],3),Zs)`.

The following [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) implementations correspond to above non-[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) codes:

```
less_than([],_) --> [].   % less_than([],_) --> [].      % less_than([],_) --> [].  
less_than([Z|Zs],X) -->   % less_than([Z|Zs],X) -->      % less_than([Z|Zs],X) -->  
   { zcompare(Ord,Z,X) }, %    { #<(Z,X,B) },            %    if_(Z #< X,[Z],[]),
   ord_lt_(Ord,Z),        %    incl_lt_(B,Z),            %    less_than(Zs,X).     
   less_than(Zs,X).       %    less_than(Zs,X).          %
                          %                              %  
ord_lt_(<,Z) --> [Z].     % incl_lt_(true ,Z) --> [Z].   % 
ord_lt_(=,_) --> [].      % incl_lt_(false,_) --> [].    %
ord_lt_(>,_) --> [].      %                              %
```

---

OK! Saving the best for last... Simply use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915) together with [`(#>)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059035/4609915)!

```
less_than(Xs,Zs,P) :-
   tfilter(#>(P),Xs,Zs).
```

Comment: I am not 100% happy with this `(#>)/3`

Comment: @false. Not happy with the interface or the implementation?

Comment: The current implementation is pretty expensive, and thus I question whether this is a good idea.

Comment: ... and this Fortranesque three-way branching, when only two would be sufficient.

Comment: @false. I see. We're on the same page here. I think the FD reification is baroque, too. But where are there 3-way branch points? Don't see it in `(#>)/3`.

Comment: `zcompare/3` is a reasonable interface, whereas `(#>)/2` and family leads to combinatorial explosion - highly non-DRY

Comment: @false. So how about `{ zcompare(Ord,Z,X) }, if_(Ord = (<), [Z], [])` in stead of the varants above?

Comment: No answer? It's time.

Answer (score 1):

The [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) variant in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32577344/4609915) is our starting point.

Consider the auxiliary non-terminal `ord_lt_//2`:

```
ord_lt_(<,Z) --> [Z].
ord_lt_(=,_) --> [].
ord_lt_(>,_) --> [].
```

These three clauses can be covered using two conditions:

1. `Ord = (<)`: the item *should* be included.
2. `dif(Ord, (<))`: it *should* **not** be included.

We can express this "either-or choice" using [`if_//3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367581/4609915):

```
less_than([],_) --> [].
less_than([Z|Zs],X) -->
   { zcompare(Ord,Z,X) },
   if_(Ord = (<), [Z], []),
   less_than(Zs,X).
```

Thus `ord_lt_//2` becomes redundant.

Net gain? 3 [lines-of-code](/questions/tagged/lines-of-code) !-)

Comment: I hoped for @lurker to answer this

Comment: Where is `if_//3` defined? (Link)

Comment: @false. so did i. the link is in the older answer, will update this answer accordingly...