# Get all elements of the list which are less than particular number

Tags: prolog

By the time I'm learning Prolog I encountered on a problem. I'm trying to make function like this

```
   ?- less_than([1,2,3,2,1,5],3,Y).
      Y= [1,2,2,1]
```

Because I was learning object-oriented programming I stacked with this and can't figure out how to solve. 
This is mine code:

```
  less_than([],X,Y).
  less_than([H|T], X, [H1|T1]) :-
            H<X, less_than(T,X,H).
```

And also, I tried with findall:

```
  less_than([],X,Y).
  less_than([H|T],X,[H1|T1]) :-
            findall(H, (H<X, less_than(T,X,Y)), Z).
```

Where I'm getting this result:

```
Y = [_G2274|_G2275]  for ?- less_than([1,2,3,4,5],3,X)
```

I know that they are unknown values but how to set values in that list? I tried to change Y with and H but it wont work.

I tried to debug it but with no success, it keeps falling apart and this is only logical explanation how to solve it for me. Any1 has an idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numbers in a list smaller than a given number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260202/numbers-in-a-list-smaller-than-a-given-number)

Answer (score 3):

I won't solve the whole issue for you, but I would like to show you how you can approach such issues in general.

A major advantage of Prolog is that you can debug issues **declaratively**. This means that you use *logical properties* of Prolog to locate the causes of unintended answers.

For example, in your case, you have the program:

```
less_than([], X, Y).
less_than([H|T], X, [H1|T1]) :-
        H < X,
        less_than(T, X, H).
```

and the following unintended **failure** of a query:

```
?- less_than([1,2,3,2,1,5], 3, Y).
false.
```

Let us use the following definition to **generalize** a Prolog program, like in GUPU:

> ```
> :- op(950,fy, *).
>
> *_.
> ```

For example, consider the following generalization, which we obtain by placing `(*)/1` in front of all goals:

```
less_than([], X, Y).
less_than([H|T], X, [H1|T1]) :-
        * H < X,
        * less_than(T, X, H).
```

With this generalization, we have:

```
?- less_than([1,2,3,2,1,5],3,Y).
Y = [_G946|_G947].
```

So, while this is now *too* general, at least the query **succeeds**.

By refining the generalization, we can narrow down the exact cause of the problem. For example:

```
less_than([], X, Y).
less_than([H|T], X, [H1|T1]) :-
        * H < X,
        less_than(T, X, H).
```

This again yields:

```
?- less_than([1,2,3,2,1,5],3,Y).
false.
```

Observe that *adding further goals* can at most *specialize* the program, never generalize it. Therefore, the *remaining* fragment must be generalized if we want this query to succeed at all.

So, if you want your query to succeed at all, you must make *at least* the following fragment succeed for the query:

```
less_than([], X, Y).
less_than([H|T], X, [H1|T1]) :-
        less_than(T, X, H).
```

Why does this currently fail? Try the following *further generalization*:

```
less_than([], /*X*/_, /*Y*/_).
less_than([H|T], /*X*/_, [/*H1*/_|/*T1*/_]) :-
        less_than(T, /*X*/_, H).
```

This **still fails**:

```
?- less_than([1,2,3,2,1,5],3,Y).
false.
```

So, we have now *reduced* this to:

```
less_than([], _, _).
less_than([H|T], _, [_|_]) :-
        less_than(T, _, H).
```

And now the point: Interestingly, the following generalization **succeeds**:

```
less_than([], _, _).
less_than([H|T], _, [_|_]) :-
        less_than(T, _, /*H*/_).
```

Therefore, this last argument of the call of `less_than/3` is a hot candidate for closer scrutiny...

Comment: I have made some changes and I think the program is working now. 
`less_than([],X,[]).
 less_than([H|T], X, [H|List]) :- 
        H<X, less_than(T, X, List).
less_than([H|T], X, List) :- H>=X, less_than(T,X, List). `

Actually I wrote all down except the last **less_than(T, X, List).** . Why is that? I figured out that I need something which will iterate through all list but I havent known how not to add that numbers `H>=X` to my last parameter. So my question now is, how is the last line different from less_than/3?
I just can't figure it out in my brain, can you help me explain it?

Comment: The last line *is* a goal of the form `less_than/3`. A good way to understand the definition is to read the clauses *declaratively*: **If** it is the case that `H >= X` *and* `List` is the list of elements of `Ts` that are *less than* `X`, **then** `List` is *also* the list of elements that are less than `X` in the list `[H|Ts]`. Analogously for the other two clauses, for example: It **is** the case that `[]` is the list of elements less than `X` that also occur in the empty list. Using **constraints** would make your program a lot **more general**, usable in other directions too!