# Prolog only check variable is instantiated

Tags: prolog, rules

In `Prolog`, is it possible to check if the `variable` is certain value only if the variable is `instantiated`.

```
? - my_rule(X).

my_rule(X):-
    X = 4,
    write('continue').
```

Here I am trying to check if the `X is 4`, if the `X is 4` then we continue, but I also want the rule to continue if the `X` is `_`, but when it is called with something else, like `X is 3` then it should not continue.

So the results would look like this:

```
?- my_rule(X).

continue
true.

?- my_rule(4).

continue
true.

?- my_rule(3).

false.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double negation ( `\+(\+(...))` ):

In your example:

```
my_rule(X):-
    \+(\+(X = 4)),
    write('continue').
```

Comment: May I ask you what would you do to check if it is `not 4`. So that it would work in every case except when the `X = 4`

Comment: @Richard: in that case you may use `\+(X==4)`

Comment: In a lot of cases `dif/2` works better (it's more expensive because it postpones goals until it can decide if the arguments are equal or not). You can also use [`iso_dif/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720685/how-to-define-and-name-the-corresponding-safe-term-comparison-predicates-in-is) which does no propagation but throws an exception in the case that cannot be decided immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `var/1`, `atom/1` and `ground/1`:

- `var(X)` is true if and only if `X` is a variable.

  ?- var(X), X= 1.
  X = 1.

  ?- X=1, var(X).
  false.

  ?- X=f(Y), var(X).
  false.
- `atom(X)` is true if `X` is an atom.

  ?- atom(a).
  true.

  ?- atom(f(a)).
  false.

  ?- atom(X).
  false.
- `ground(X)` is true if `X` is ground (does not contain variables).

  ?- ground(f(a)).
  true.

  ?- ground(f(X)).
  false.

The three predicates are deterministic (i.e. do not backtrack) and you can safely negate them.

Your code become something like this:

```
my_rule(4) :-
   % handle the 4 case
my_rule(X) :-
   var(X),
   % general case
```

I'm just not sure if this is, what you want. In most programs, there should be no necessity to handle the variable only case separately. Also be aware that such meta-logical tests are outside the scope of classical logic. If compare the queries `X = 1, var(X)` and `var(X), X = 1`, you can see that the conjunction is not commutative anymore but in logic A ∧ B = B ∧ A holds.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_rule(X):-
    check(X),
    write('continue').

% A fact used to check a value.
check(4).

% A predicate that checks if X is unbound, e.g. a variable.
check(X) :-
    var(X).
```

Verification of desired results.

```
?- my_rule(X).
continue
X = 4 ;
continue
true.

?- my_rule(4).
continue
true ;
false.

?- my_rule(3).
false.
```

Comment: Even though this answer looks cleaner, I have to accept the `gusbro` one since I have multiple cases of this example and that one fits better, but thank you for answering.

Comment: Can I asko you also how you would do it  - check if it is `not 4`. So that it would work in every case except when the `X = 4`

Comment: @Richard Et tu, Brute?