# getting a prolog program to print out results instead of booleans

Tags: prolog

imagine a 2d map with 6 regions R1-R6.  Each region should be colored in with 1 of 4 colors, but no adjacent regions can be the same color.

here is my code:

```
% #1 initial facts
next(red,green).
next(red,blue).
next(red,yellow).
next(green,red).
next(green,blue).
next(green,yellow).
next(blue,green).
next(blue,yellow).
next(blue,red).
next(yellow,red).
next(yellow,blue).
next(yellow,green).
% #1 actual program
color(R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6).
color(R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6):-
    % region adjacency relations
    next(R1,R2),
    next(R1,R3),
    next(R1,R4),
    next(R2,R4),
    next(R2,R5),
    next(R3,R4),
    next(R3,R6),
    next(R4,R5),
    next(R4,R6).
```

Expected output:

```
R1= red, R2= blue, R3= blue, R4= green, R5= red, R6= red
```

My Output:

```
true
```

what am I doing wrong? Is this even wrong? Even if my code is successfully finding the right color configuration, how do I get it to print out its findings?

Comment: Depends which prolog. Does yours have a print command? If you put it as the last clause, it will only print if all preceding clauses succeed.

Comment: Your program is currently too general due to the first clause of `color/6`. You get the solution you expect (as one among many different solutions) if you simply remove that first clause.

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something like that. I started learning the stupid language last week.

Comment: @mat feel free to write that in an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is currently too general due to the first clause of `color/6`. You get the solution you expect (as one among many different solutions) if you simply remove that first clause.

There is also a more beautiful way to write your program:

```
regions(Rs):-
        Rs = [R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6],
        % neighbouring regions have different colors
        dif(R1, R2),
        dif(R1, R3),
        dif(R1, R4),
        dif(R2, R4),
        dif(R2, R5),
        dif(R3, R4),
        dif(R3, R6),
        dif(R4, R5),
        dif(R4, R6),
        maplist(color, Rs).

color(red).
color(green).
color(blue).
color(yellow).
```

Example query and sample solutions:

```
?- regions(Rs).
Rs = [red, green, green, blue, red, red] ;
Rs = [red, green, green, blue, red, yellow] ;
Rs = [red, green, green, blue, yellow, red] ;
etc.
```

Notice the use of `dif/2` ([prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)) to state that two terms are different.

For more serious map coloring tasks, consider using [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) constraints.

Comment: s(X): How about using a different name than `regions/1`?

Comment: Thank you! Regarding predicate names, there is almost always room for improvement. The point I would predominantly  like to stress in this example is that the variables themselves denote the regions. There is no need for any indirection! A more specific name would be for example `regions_with_admissible_coloring/1`.

Comment: OK. Names are always the hardest part:)

Comment: You're right. But this is a class project names have been pre-specified. Nothing I can do.

Answer (score 0):

in case your Prolog doesn't offer dif/2, or you are willing to better understand the basic of this language, here is a possible correction of your code:

```
next(R1,R2) :-
    select(R1, [red, green, blue, yellow], Cs),
    member(R2, Cs).

color(R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6):-
    % region adjacency relations
    next(R1,R2),
    next(R1,R3),
    next(R1,R4),
    next(R2,R4),
    next(R2,R5),
    next(R3,R4),
    next(R3,R6),
    next(R4,R5),
    next(R4,R6).
```

this is marginally more efficient - on the inference count - than using dif/2.

*edit* still better, using iso_dif/2, or the 'old style' version

```
next(R1, R2) :- color(R1), color(R2), R1 \= R2.
```

of course, color/1 comes from mat' answer

Comment: Is this really faster than  `next(R1, R2) :- color(R1), color(R2), iso_dif(R1,R2).`? (using [`iso_dif/2`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20238931/772868)).

Comment: even with dif/2 - highly optimized, afaik  in SWI-Prolog implementation - the difference is small - just 13,333 vs 27,878 inferences to compute all 192 solutions. Just, I wonder what dif/2 implementers think about iso_dif/2. I find the name a bit misleading...

Comment: Counting inferences is not a reliable **performance** measure: Your goal `select(R1, [red, green, blue, yellow], Cs),` counts as much as `color(R1)`. What exactly is misleading for `iso_dif/2`?

Comment: @false: just a **bit** misleading, really

Comment: If you really want to make a **constructive** comment, you could add it to the actual definition of `iso_dif/2`.

Comment: @false: iso_dif/2 and color/1 make the better inference count so far, I apologize...

Comment: Performance comparison (iso_dif,capelli,mat) all[s]: SICStus:(0.76,1.02,2.51),SWI:(2.15,4.6,6.79).

Comment: Your last optimization using `(\=)/2` directly, comes at a price: Should `next/2` contain terms with variables, it may be incorrect. Trading performance for correctness is quite undesirable.