# Prolog integer comparison fails with error_type error

Tags: prolog

I am trying to resolve exercise 2 of lists construction section of [this page](http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/lists.html):

> *Write a program to delete all reference of a particular item from a list. It should have three arguments. The list you wish to use, the
>   item to delete, and the resulting list.*

Here is the script I came up with:

```
delete_all([],Y,[]).
delete_all([X|T],Y,[X|Result]):- 
    X =\= Y,                               /* is X different than Y       */
    delete_all(T,Y,Result).                /* if so then go find the rest */
delete_all([ThrowAway|Tail],Y,Result):-    /* disgard the head            */
    delete_all(Tail,Y,Result).             /* and look in the tail        */
```

And here are the corrects results that it should give:`delete_all([a,b,a,c,a,d],b,Result).`

```
% delete_all([a,b,a,c,a,d],a,Result).
% Result = [b,c,d]
% delete_all([a,b,a,c,a,d],b,Result).
% Result = [a,a,c,a,d]
% delete_all([a,b,a,c,a,d],prolog,Result).
% Result = [a,b,a,c,a,d]
```

Instead I am getting this error:

```
| ?- delete_all([a,b,a,c,a,d],a,Result).
uncaught exception: error(type_error(evaluable,a/0),(=\=)/2)
```

I am using gprolog under ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you

Comment: `=\=` is for *arithmetic* inequality.

Comment: @coder, my bad. sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more efficient answer using `if_/3` from module `reif`:

```
delete([],_,[]).
delete([H|T],X,L):- if_( 
                         H = X,
                         delete(T,X,L),
                         (L = [H|L1], delete(T,X,L1))
                       ).
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all you're getting a warning about singleton variable in your first line because Y is a singleton, so you need to replace with:

```
delete_all([],_,[]).
```

Now the error is due to `=\=` **which is only used for arithmetic** you need to use either `\=` or even better iso predicate `dif/2` which preserves logical purity.

The complete code now:

```
delete_all([],_,[]).
delete_all([X|T],Y,[X|Result]):- dif(X,Y), delete_all(T,Y,Result).               
delete_all([Y|Tail],Y,Result):- delete_all(Tail,Y,Result).
```

Comment: I am getting this error now: | ?- delete_all([a,b,a,c,a,d],a,Result).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,dif/2),delete_all/3)

Comment: It says that it is not defined, currently i'm using swipl. I just searched and in gprolog there is compare/3 predicate so you could try the edited question in a minute...

Comment: I just tested with swi-prolog, dif is recognized but my algorithm is not correct. i am gonna update the question

Comment: Sorry I missed a detail in the last clause you should have: `delete_all([Y|Tail],Y,Result)`  not `ThrowAway` as you had before, you need to state that the head is same with `Y`!! Also I tried with `gnuprolog` and the version with compare seems fine.

Comment: @Karim: Take coder's first and correct definition and  [this definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238931) for `dif/2`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a functional design. You need to look at **foldl/4** and  **difference lists** (to understand U-U , [In|U]-U and append_dl).

```
delete_one(To_Remove, To_Remove, Cur, Cur).
delete_one(To_Remove, In, Cur, Next) :-
    dif(To_Remove, In),
    append_dl(Cur, [In|U]-U, Next).

append_dl(A-B, B-C, A-C).

delete_all(In, To_Remove, Out) :-
    foldl(delete_one(To_Remove), In, U-U, Out-[]).
```

Example:

```
 ?- delete_all([a,b,a,c,a,d],a,Result).
Result = [b,c,d] ;
false.

 ?- delete_all([a,b,a,c,a,d],X,[b,c,d]).
X = a ;
false.

 ?- delete_all([Y,b,Y,c,Y,d],X,[b,c,d]).
Y = X,
dif(X,d),
dif(X,c),
dif(X,b) ;
false.
```