# NU-Prolog's and Gödel's logical and sound `if-then-else` extension

Tags: prolog, logic-programming, logical-purity

A [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0743106696000684) about [mercury](/questions/tagged/mercury) says the following:

> The if-then-else and negation constructs in most variants of Prolog are non-logical and unsound: they can cause the system to compute answers which are inconsistent with the program viewed as a logical theory. Some existing logic programming systems such as **NU-Prolog and Gödel provide logical and sound replacements for these Prolog constructs**. Unfortunately, these systems enforce safety via runtime groundness checks. This effect can increase the runtime of a program by an arbitrarily large factor; if the goals checked for groundness include large terms, the checks can be prohibitively expensive.

NU-Prolog and Gödel look rather dead and non-free, but I still wonder:

- What are these logical and sound `if-then-else` replacements?
- Do they have analogs in SWI or GNU Prologs?
- How do they work? How *could* they work? Adding logical negation to Prolog turns it into general FOL, right? You would basically need a general FOL theorem prover to work with it?
- Are they different from [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358456/prolog-union-for-a-u-b-u-c/27358600#27358600)? [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358456/prolog-union-for-a-u-b-u-c/27358600#27358600) has to be extended to be used with new conditions. Would one have to do this in NU-Prolog and Gödel also?

Comment: "How do they work?" not too well apparently

Comment: @TA_intern Come to think of it, `if_(=(...), ...)` uses `dif/2` which also requires groundness checks, no? It sounds like NU-Prolog and Gödel generalized the same mechanism somehow....

Comment: @MaxB: There are no groundness checks in any implementation of `dif/2`. Think of `dif([], [_|_])` or `dif(A,A)` which both are not ground, yet they already succeed resp. fail. And this, independently of whether constraints are used or not. See [this sketch](https://github.com/mthom/scryer-prolog/issues/135#issuecomment-488348886) for a minimal complete implementation. Or maybe look at [`iso_dif/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238931/772868) first.

Comment: See [Indexing dif/2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01590) which mentions MU-Prolog's if-then-else and also constructive negation. (Which would be the next step after giving up groundness).

Comment: I am curious as to why @false did not give these. See bios for following which include such desired predicates. [false](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false) and [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4609915/repeat)

Comment: @GuyCoder: "did not give these". What do you mean by these?

Comment: @false MaxB is asking questions about predicates that I think of as the pure versions of predicates, e.g. `if_/3`. Then you noted `dif/2` and so I was pointing out where there are more such predicates that I think of as the pur versions of predicates and list of these predicates can be found in your bios. The reason I was curious as to why you did not give these is that the way I see the question and the way you see the question must be different and thus there is something to learn.

Comment: Interesting NU-Prolog [Paper buried in the 1987-12 issue of "The quarterly bulletin of the Computer Society of the IEEE technical committee on Data Engineering"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220282520_The_NU-Prolog_Deductive_Database_System) is considered a "deductive database system" not a "logic programming language" (but it does have function symbols, it seems).

Comment: _Adding logical not to Prolog turns it into general FOL, right?_ This "not" is still the usual "negation as failure" -- it just refuses to compute nonsense by making sure it is only called for variables that are ground if they are visible outside of the `\+`(which is excellent). That's still not "strong negation" though, so no FOL. (Sidenote: Currently reading "Vivid Logic" by Gerd Wagner ... Classical Logic and thus FOL based on Classical Logic is a misfit for practically anything outside of mathematics ... and even for mathematics itself. So why target it?)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer They say "logical negation", so I don't think they mean "negation-as-failure".

Comment: @MaxB I am pretty sure they don't support strong negation. For that, you need Answer Set Programming or similar much different systems not based on SLD resolution. What they want to do is make negation-as-failure sound ...

Comment: @GuyCoder A hodgepodge of "almost pure" predicates is not a good sign that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425800/) can be answered positively: If only a handful of primitives is enough, why do we need to hand-design so many more, using impure constructs?

Comment: Did you read the [Nu-Prolog manual](https://edoras.sdsu.edu/doc/Nu-Prolog_Manual.pdf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A break through in if-then-else could be a new annotation.
By annotation I understand things like mode declarations,
determinancy declarations, etc.. For an if then else, a
complete declaration would be nice. Lets assume we could
declare a predicate or built-in  p/n complete. This would
mean it has the property for ground arguments t1,..,tn:

```
   T |- p(t1,..,tn)

- or -

   T |- ~p(t1,..,tn)
```

Or in short it would be a decidable predicate if the theory T is recursively enumerable. If we then recall that if-then-else is logically:

```
    ITE(A,B,C) == (A => B) & (~A => C)
```

We could then use the complete annotation as follows. Lets
assume A = p(t1,..,tn). Because of the annotation the Prolog
system would try to prove A. If it doesn't succeed, because
of the complete annotation, the Prolog system can infer that
~A would succeed. And therefore it can use the else branch
without a proof attempt of ~A.

But interestingly this is already what the ISO core
standard if-then-else does, (A->B;C) does also only prove
A once. So whats the problem? I guess the problem is
that A might be more complex and not necessarily ground.
Or even that a predicate p/n might be incomplete, or
we even don't know whether it is complete. And in all
these cases the ISO core standard nevertheless allows
us to use the (A->B;C).

The groundness problem can sometimes be solved by using a runtime
groundness checks. This is probably what Mercury refers to:

```
    when(ground(A), (A->B;C))
```

SWI-Prolog even applies a trick to make the groundness
check cheaper, see also some further [discussion](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/is-there-a-whened-2-predicate/3261/8) on Discourse:

```
%!  trigger_ground(@Term, :Goal)
%
%   Trigger Goal when Term becomes   ground.  The current implementation
%   uses nonground/2, waiting for an   atribtrary  variable and re-check
%   Term  when  this  variable   is    bound.   Previous   version  used
%   term_variables and suspended  on  a   term  constructed  from  these
%   variables. It is clear  that  either   approach  performs  better on
%   certain types of terms. The term_variables/2  based approach wins on
%   large terms that are almost  ground.   Possibly  we need a nonground
%   that also returns the number of tests   performed  and switch to the
%   term_variables/2 based approach if this becomes large.

trigger_ground(X, Goal) :-
    (   nonground(X, V)
    ->  '$suspend'(V, when, trigger_ground(X, Goal))
    ;   call(Goal)
).
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this review of MU- and NU-Prologs [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0743106694900310), if anyone's interested:

[image]