# Relate Roman and Arabic numerals

Tags: prolog, roman-numerals

How to relate Roman and Arabic numerals up to 899999 in a pure manner? And this time without using arithmetic! Thus without `(is)/2` nor `clpfd`/`clpz`/`clpq`. Lacking any means to relate to integers, Arabic numerals have to be represented as a list of characters. Thus [`:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868). The characters used for Roman numbers are below.

As usual, Arabic numerals do not have leading zeroes, nor spaces in between, the Roman numerals use the "common" subtractive rules. See below.

What I have tried so far was to use integers. But this here should be without them. Efficiency isn't the goal, but termination is.

The pure part includes `dif/2` and [`dif_si/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238931/772868) although 90 facts could express the inequality between decimal digits as well.

```
?- arabic_roman(A,R) , false.
   false.  % it terminates, we have only 899999 numbers, very finite
?- arabic_roman("0",R).
   false. % no zero
?- arabic_roman(['0'|_],R).
   false. % and in general no leading zeros
?- R=[_], arabic_roman(A,R).
   R = "I", A = "1"
;  R = "V", A = "5"
;  R = "X", A = "10"
;  R = "L", A = "50"
;  R = "C", A = "100"
;  R = "D", A = "500" % no apostrophus "IↃ"
;  R = "M", A = "1000" % no "CIↃ"
;  R = "ↁ", A = "5000" % idem
;  R = "ↂ", A = "10000"
;  R = "ↇ", A = "50000"
;  R = "ↈ", A = "100000"
;  R = "@", A = "500000" % poor support in Unicode
;  false.
?- arabic_roman("899999",R).
   R = "@ↈↈↈↂↈMↂCMXCIX" % the largest number
;  false.
?- arabic_roman(  ['9',_,_, _,_,_],R).
   false. % no six digit number starting with 9
?- arabic_roman( [_, _,_,_, _,_,_|_],R).
   false. % no seven or more digit numbers
?- setof(R,A^arabic_roman(A,R),Rs),length(Rs,N).
   Rs = ["@","@C","@CC","@CCC"|_], N = 899999.  % terms omitted at _
?- setof(A,R^arabic_roman(A,R),As),length(As,N).
   As = ["1","10","100","1000","10000","100000","100001"|_], N = 899999.
?- setof(A-R,arabic_roman(A,R),ARs),length(ARs,N).
   ARs = ["1"-"I","10"-"X","100"-"C","1000"-"M","10000"-"ↂ"|_], N = 899999.
?- arabic_roman(A,"IL").
   false. % no generalized subtractive rule
?- arabic_roman(A,"IM").
   false. % idem
?- arabic_roman(A,R), phrase((...,[X,X,X,X],...),R).
   false.
```

Comment: Doesn't "Efficiency isn't the goal, but termination is" mean that an answer with fewer unwanted choicepoints is preferable?

Comment: Leftover choice points in current implementations are first of all an efficiency issue. Neither universal nor existential termination is affected by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 15 clauses (depending how we are counting). It terminates.

```
:- use_module(library(dcgs)).
:- use_module(library(lists)).
:- use_module(library(dif)).

foldl(G__3, [], S, S) --> [].
foldl(G__3, [E|Es], S0, S) --> call(G__3, E, S0, S1), foldl(G__3, Es, S1, S).

d5u('0', s([R10|Rs],[R5,R1|Ds]), s([R1,R5,R10|Rs],Ds)) --> [].
d5u('1', s(Rs,[R5,R1|Ds]), s([R1,R5|Rs],Ds)) --> [R1].
d5u('2', s(Rs,[R5,R1|Ds]), s([R1,R5|Rs],Ds)) --> [R1,R1].
d5u('3', s(Rs,[R5,R1|Ds]), s([R1,R5|Rs],Ds)) --> [R1,R1,R1].
d5u('4', s(Rs,[R5,R1|Ds]), s([R1,R5|Rs],Ds)) --> [R1,R5].
d5u('5', s(Rs,[R5,R1|Ds]), s([R1,R5|Rs],Ds)) --> [R5].
d5u('6', s(Rs,[R5,R1|Ds]), s([R1,R5|Rs],Ds)) --> [R5,R1].
d5u('7', s(Rs,[R5,R1|Ds]), s([R1,R5|Rs],Ds)) --> [R5,R1,R1].
d5u('8', s(Rs,[R5,R1|Ds]), s([R1,R5|Rs],Ds)) --> [R5,R1,R1,R1].
d5u('9', s([R10|Rs],[R5,R1|Ds]), s([R1,R5,R10|Rs],Ds)) --> [R1,R10].

au5(_, s([R1,R5|Rs0],Rs), s(Rs0,[R5,R1|Rs])).

arabic_roman([C|Cs]) -->
    { foldl(au5, [C|Cs], s("IVXLCDMↁↂↇↈ@",[]), S0) },
    foldl(d5u,[C|Cs], S0, s([_|_],[])),
    { dif(C, '0') }.

arabic_roman(A, R) :-
    phrase(arabic_roman(A), R).
```

Comment: Stylistic comment: `R5->V,R1->I,R10->X`. But I am really impressed...

Comment: `foldl//4` gives me some headaches. After all, what does this call//4 construct mean? The variable name suggests, that its first argument is a non-terminal lacking three arguments. Currently we have only call//1, and the argument is a goal (not a non-terminal) lacking two arguments. So there is this distinction between non-terminals and predicates. And this call//4 mixes this up.

Comment: Just to be clear, it works...

Comment: `call//N` is like `call/N` but for DCGs.

Comment: So what is the first argument of `call//4`? Is it a non-terminal or a goal?

Comment: It's a non-terminal.

Comment: You use it like it would be one. But you could equally well use it as a goal lacking the corresponding arguments.

Comment: One way out would be to define `phrase//2,3,...`

Comment: But with `call//N` not much change is needed to adopt it but `phrase//N` would be like `maplist/N`.

Comment: actually the (internal) implementation would be almost identical, thus phrase(NT__1, A1, S0,S) :- call(NT__1, A1, S0,S). phrase(NT__2, A1, A2, S0,S) :- call(NT__2, A1, A2, S0,S). phrase(NT__3, A1, A2, A3, S0,S) :- call(NT__3, A1, A2, A3, S0,S). etc. Except that for NT__1 and NT__2 there would be some extra checking for control constructs. No such check is necessary from NT__3 on.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. I have changed some roman symbols because my setup has poor support for unicode, so `P` is 5000, `T` is 10000, `F` is 50000, `Q` is 100000 and `@` is 500000.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

arabic_roman(A, R):- phrase(arabic_roman(A), R).

arabic_roman([A|As])-->
  { dif(A, '0') },
  arabic_roman_skip("Q@!TFMPCDXLIV!!", [A|As]).

arabic_roman_skip([P,_,_,P1,C1|S], As)-->
  arabic_roman_skip([P1,C1,P|S], As).
arabic_roman_skip(S, As)-->
  arabic_roman(S, As).

arabic_roman("!!I", [])-->[].
arabic_roman([P,C,N,P1,C1|S], [A|As])-->
  arabic_digit_roman(A, P,C,N),
  arabic_roman([P1,C1,P|S], As).

arabic_digit_roman('0', _,_,_) --> [].
arabic_digit_roman('1', P,_,_) --> [P].
arabic_digit_roman('2', P,_,_) --> [P,P].
arabic_digit_roman('3', P,_,_) --> [P,P,P].
arabic_digit_roman('4', P,C,_) --> [P,C].
arabic_digit_roman('5', _,C,_) --> [C].
arabic_digit_roman('6', P,C,_) --> [C,P].
arabic_digit_roman('7', P,C,_) --> [C,P,P].
arabic_digit_roman('8', P,C,_) --> [C,P,P,P].
arabic_digit_roman('9', P,_,N) --> [P,N], {dif(N,'!')}.
```

Sample runs:

```
?- arabic_roman("899999",R).
R = [@, 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'T', 'Q', 'M', 'T', 'C', 'M', 'X', 'C', 'I', 'X'].
?- time((setof(A1,R^A^(arabic_roman(A,R), atom_codes(A1,A)),As),length(As,N))).
% 3,118,631 inferences, 1.841 CPU in 1.879 seconds (98% CPU, 1694161 Lips)
As = ['1', '10', '100', '1000', '10000', '100000', '100001', '100002', '100003'|...],
N = 899999.
```

Comment: These pcn-facts could be a single list.

Comment: `s/N \= '!'/dif(N,!)/`

Comment: @false: yes it could be a single list, but I'd have to tweak it to get the starting template

Comment: I didn't understand your second comment. N at that point is always ground

Comment: Both question and bounty are about a pure solution. And `\=` isn't. With `dif/2` or `dif_si/2` it would be.

Comment: The advantage of the list would be: More DRYness, and even a bit more efficient as it does not rely on deep indexing (where is that implemented?). Same for the `Rs` as non-terminal. Making arabic_digit_roman/3 a non-terminal would not increase the clause count and would avoid the `Rs`

Comment: You are right. I updated my answer and it is more efficient now.

Comment: Leaves unwanted choicepoints, even when either (or both) side is ground.

Comment: `arabic_roman(A,R),false` with Scryer before  47.687s and now 3.084s.

Comment: This atom_code/2 should be rather a atom_chars/2.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't quite seem worth using DCG:

```
% Need nan, to fill the last group of [I, V, X]
roman_chars(['I', 'V', 'X', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'M', 'ↁ', 'ↂ', 'ↇ', 'ↈ', '@', nan]).

arabic_digit_roman('0', _I, _V, _X, T, T).
arabic_digit_roman('1', I, _, _, [I|T], T).
arabic_digit_roman('2', I, _, _, [I, I|T], T).
arabic_digit_roman('3', I, _, _, [I, I, I|T], T).
arabic_digit_roman('4', I, V, _, [I, V|T], T).
arabic_digit_roman('5', _, V, _, [V|T], T).
arabic_digit_roman('6', I, V, _, [V, I|T], T).
arabic_digit_roman('7', I, V, _, [V, I, I|T], T).
arabic_digit_roman('8', I, V, _, [V, I, I, I|T], T).
arabic_digit_roman('9', I, _, X, [I, X|T], T) :-
    dif(X, nan).

arabic_roman(A, R) :-
    % No leading zero
    A = [First|_],
    dif(First, '0'),
    roman_chars(RCs),
    arabic_roman_(A, RCs, R).

arabic_roman_([], _, []).
arabic_roman_([AH|AT], RCs, R) :-
    arabic_length(AT, RCs, I, V, X, RCs0),
    arabic_digit_roman(AH, I, V, X, R, T),
    arabic_roman_(AT, RCs0, T).
    
arabic_length([], [I, V, X|_], I, V, X, [I]).
arabic_length([_|T], [II, VV|R], I, V, X, [II, VV|RC]) :-
    arabic_length(T, R, I, V, X, RC).
```

There are no unwanted choicepoints when the Arabic list is ground, e.g.:

```
?- arabic_roman(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], R).
R = [ↈ, ↂ, ↂ, 'M', 'M', 'M', 'C', 'D', 'L', 'V', 'I'].
```

Performance in swi-prolog:

```
?- time((bagof(A-R, arabic_roman(A, R), ARs), length(ARs, N))).
% 2,312,762 inferences, 0.726 CPU in 0.726 seconds (100% CPU, 3184610 Lips)
ARs = [['1']-['I'], ['2']-['I', 'I'], ['3']-['I', 'I', 'I'], ...
N = 899999.
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using Unicode characters?

Comment: Only because e.g. ↂ doesn't have its spacing quite correct, when viewed in Linux terminal. Can change later.

Comment: Improved termination when Arabic list is ground (not relying on JIT indexing).

Comment: How does atom_codes/2 fit in? This is about chars.

Comment: Changed performance test.